`Application Error : The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)`
In my Ionic 5 Application, After downloading and installing, while opening the Application, Im getting popup "Application Error :  The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)" above login page.
I tried with the solution
<platform name="android"> **<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />** </platform>
than also I'm getting the same error,
In many devices, after killing and reopening the app, issue get resolved but some devices, after killing the app and restarting ,** Issue is not getting resolved** and continuously getting.
After reinstalling the Application, **Issue Persists **
